# Use same variable twice in a python function

Tags: python

In my function, I only want to explicitly pass a single variable but It's being used twice. When I run the code, I get an error

> def quickSort(arr, left=0, right=len(arr)-1):
>
> > NameError: name 'arr' is not defined

```
def quickSort(arr, left=0, right=len(arr)-1):
    # Base Case
    if left < right:
        pivotIdx = pivot(arr,left,right)
        # left side
        quickSort(arr, left, right=pivotIdx-1)
        # right side
        quickSort(arr, pivotIdx+1, right)
    return arr
```

```
arr = [4,8,2,1,5,7,6,3]
quickSort(arr)
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: There's nothing wrong in using one variable multiple times. You must've been given with the line of code where this error was thrown, what is it? Maybe in `pivot` function your array variable isn't called `arr`

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov The line of code is ``def quickSort(arr, left=0, right=len(arr)-1):``

Comment: Oh I see, you can't default your argument `right` with value `len(arr)-1`

Comment: Because the value should be known without knowing any other argument (typically it should be some constant)

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov Any work around without explicitly specifying value for **right**?

Comment: Please see the linked duplicate for the general technique.

Comment: Some clunky workaround would be to default it to `-1`, and then in your function check if it's `-1` and reassign with `len(arr)-1` if so

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: you have to calculate it inside function - you could use `None` for this - `def quickSort(arr, left=0, right=None): if not right: right = len(arr)-1`